# Modify legend - remove points, keep lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to modify the legend of in the ggplot2-plot below. I want to remove the points from the legend and keep the lines. I want to do this in a more complex plot, I hope the solution for the problem stated here transfers to the more complicated plot, too!

```
library('ggplot2')
iris %>% ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

Thanks a lot and best greetings,
Sebastian

I tried different calls of `guides` but could not achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set `show.legend=FALSE` in `geom_point` to not show the points in the legend key:

```r
library('ggplot2')

iris |> 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) + 
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]